# Filtrar por cada elemento de un arreglo de objetos

Tags: javascript

vengo trabajando en un proyecto y tengo que filtrar por la propiedad genero la cual es un array de objetos, el cual contiene como propiedades id y name. La cuestion esta propiedad puede que tenga 1 solo objeto, o tenga mas, he logrado mostrar por pantalla los resultados cuyo valor es el que estoy tomando, pero solo si este valor se encuentre de primero y no evalua el resto del array, dejando por fuera resultados que debieran mostrarse.
A continuación muestro lo realizado y lo que estoy tratando de hacer, muchas gracias

```
 case FILTER_BY_GENRES:
        const allVideoGames = state.allVideoGames;
        const statusGenre = action.payload === 'Todos' 
        ? allVideoGames
    //acá es donde logro filtrar solo por la primera similitud
        : allVideoGames.filter(el => el.genres[0].name === action.payload);
    //y esta linea es donde estoy tratando de evaluar todo el array genres
        //:allVideoGames.map(el => el.genres.filter(e => e.name === action.payload)) 
        return {
            ...state,
            videoGames:statusGenre
        }
```

Comment: Lo que no aclaras es qué es `action.payload`

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien lo que dices, es lo que hace la línia comentada de análisis de todo el array genres:

```
allVideoGames.map(el => el.genres.filter(e => e.name === action.payload))
```

Si comentas la línia del filter y descomentas esta, tu programa no hace lo que quires?

Sino te funciona, deberias especificar un ejemplo tanto del contenido de allVideoGames como del resultado esperado según el action.payload para poder ayudarte.

Comment: mi amigo logre darle solucion con un some, dejo la linea que cambie
`:allVideoGames.filter(el => el.genres?.some(g => g.name.toLowerCase() === action.payload.toLowerCase()))`

Comment: @GuerreroAntonio tu comentario debe ser una respuesta. Luego, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te ha sido más útil.